# What is the good example of using 'func_get_arg' in PHP?

Tags: php

I just have found out that there is a function called `func_get_arg` in PHP which enables developer to use variant style of getting arguments. 
It seems to be very useful because number of argument can now be arbitrary, but I cannot think of any good example of using it.

What are the some examples of using this function to fully benefit its polymorphic characteristic?

Comment: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-arg.php  Scroll down to `Examples`, then read `User Contributed Notes`

Comment: `sprintf` and `max` are good examples of functions which can deal with an arbitrary number of arguments. Usually you want to use it with uniformly typed parameters.

Comment: You don't mean 'polymorphic': the term you're looking for is 'variadic': http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I usually use `func_get_args()` which is easier to use if wanting multiple arguments.

For example, to recreate PHP's `max()`.

```
function max() {
   $max = -PHP_INT_MAX;
   foreach(func_get_args() as $arg) {
      if ($arg > $max) {
          $max = $arg;
      }
   }
   return $max;
}
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/mRdBN5MK).

Now you can do `echo max(1,5,7,3)` and get `7`.

Comment: You know, you can reduce, if you'll forgive the pun, that down to `array_reduce(func_get_args(), 'max')`, and it'll work with negative numbers too.

Comment: @Keith Maybe I should have made that initial number `-PHP_INT_MAX`.

Comment: Only problem with that is that if you're given no arguments, the answer is `-PHP_INT_MAX`. `array_reduce($a, 'max')` will work even for an empty array, in which case it'll return `null`. We're getting a wee bit off topic here. :-)

Comment: @Keith If doing that, I may as well use PHP's `max()` directly. :P

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't entirely clear there - my `max()` is meant to be a two argument function that behaves like the built-in `max()` does for two arguments. Should've been more accurate there.

Comment: Beware that before PHP 5.3 you can't use `func_get_arg[s]` directly as an argument to other functions.

Answer (score 4):

As of php5.6, there isn't a use case of `func_get_arg` anymore; its functionality has been replaced by the [variadic function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list) using the `...` syntax:

```
/**
 * @param array $arguments
 */
public function poit(...$arguments)
{
     foreach($arguments as $argument) {
         ...
     }
}
```

This is especially useful if there are methods that are overloaded at the end; one does need to filter out the first arguments anymore, as showcased by [an example](http://andreas.heigl.org/2014/04/26/new-and-cool-features-in-php5-6/):

Old style using `func_get_arg`:

```
function foo($a, $b) {
    $c = array();
    if (func_num_args() > 2) {
        for($i = 0; $i < func_num_args()-2; $i++) {
            $c[] = func_get_arg($i+2);
        }
    }
    var_dump($a, $b, $c)
    // Do something
}
foo('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
```

Newer variadic style;

```
function foo($a, $b, …$c) {
    var_dump($a, $b, $c);
    // Do something
}
foo('a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
```

Both foo produce the same output, one is much simpler to write.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you are using the term "polymorphism" totally wrong. Polymorphism is a concept in object-oriented programming, and it has nothing to do with variable number of arguments in functions.

In my experience, all `func_get_args` allows you to do is add a little syntactic sugar.

Think of a function that can take any number of integers and return their sum. (I 'm cheating, as this already exists in `array_sum`. But cheating is good if it keeps the example simple). You could do it this way:

```
// you can leave "array" out; I have it because we should be getting one here
function sum1(array $integers) {
    return array_sum($integers);
}
```

Now you would call this like so:

```
$sum = sum1(array(1));
$sum = sum1(array(1, 2, 3, 4));
```

This isn't very pretty. But we can do better:

```
function sum2() {
    $integers = func_get_args();
    return array_sum($integers);
}
```

Now you can call it like this:

```
$sum = sum2(1);
$sum = sum2(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's say we have multiple arrays containing data in which we need to search across the keys for their values without merging these arrays.

The arrays are like:

```
$a = array('a' => 5, 'b' => 6);
$b = array('a' => 2, 'b' => 8);
$c = array('a' => 7, 'b' => 3);
```

In that case, say we need to get all the values of the key `a` from all the arrays. We can write a function that take in arbitrary number of arrays to search in.

```
// we need the key, and at least 1 array to search in
function simpleSearchArrays($key, $a1){
    $arrays = func_get_args();
    array_shift($arrays); // remove the first argument, which is the key
    $ret = array();
    foreach($arrays as $a){
        if(array_key_exists($key, $a)){
            $ret[] = $a[$key];
        }
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

So if we use the function:

```
 $x = simpleSearchArrays('a', $a, $b, $c);
```

`$x` will then contain `array(5, 2, 7)`.

Answer (score 1):

I hardly ever use `func_get_arg()`, but I do use its cousin `func_get_args()` quite a bit. Here's one example, a function along the lines of the `echo` statement that entity encodes all its arguments:

```
function ee() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    echo implode('', array_map('htmlentities', $args));
}
```

I use that function quite a bit.

Here's another useful example, a function that does the same job as SQL's `COALESCE()` function.

```
function coalesce() {
    $args = func_get_args();
    foreach ($args as $arg) {
        if (!is_null($arg)) {
            return $arg;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

It returns the first non-null argument passed in, or `null` if there's no such argument.

Comment: [You could remove that first argument](http://codepad.org/Gil0Xi29) to `implode()`.

Comment: Force of habit - I've been writing code in PHP since shortly after PHP 4.0 appeared.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I don't think there is a good use case for it inside a normal function. As a control freak I like to know exactly what is being passed to my functions and I like to know exactly what I'm passing.

However, it can be use full  for things like Dynamic/Static URL routing. When you are rewriting (via mod_rewrite) the URL args to a single bootstrap.

In this sense, you can have arguments that don't necessarily need to exist with every page request.

Answer (score 1):

Gets an array of the function's argument list.

This function may be used in conjunction with `func_get_arg()` and `func_num_args()` to allow user-defined functions to accept variable-length argument lists.

```
<?php
        function foo()
        {
            $numargs = func_num_args();
            echo "Number of arguments: $numargs \n";
            if ($numargs >= 2) {
                echo "Second argument is: " . func_get_arg(1) . "\n";
            }
            $arg_list = func_get_args();
            for ($i = 0; $i < $numargs; $i++) {
                echo "Argument $i is: " . $arg_list[$i] . "\n";
            }
        }

        foo(1, 2, 3);
?>
```