# Method signature in php like xyz(x1,x2,x3,....) vs xyz($args) which one is best practice?

Tags: php

Method signature in php like xyz(x1,x2,x3,....) vs xyz($args) which one is best practice?

```
function xyz(x1,x2,x3,x4....){
//do somthing
}
 ------------Vs----------
$args = [x1 => x1,x2 => x2,x3 => x3,x4 => x4...]
public function xyz($args){
     x1=$args[x1];
     x2=$args[x2];
     x3=$args[x3];
     x4=$args[x4];
}
```

Comment: You may have a look at [php func_get_args](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5268079/what-is-the-good-example-of-using-func-get-arg-in-php).

Comment: I'd say this is opinion based

Comment: i am try to know what is best practice?

Answer (score 1):

With the first situation, you can add the Type Hinting and the default value of arguments.
http://php.net/manual/fr/functions.arguments.php

If you are Overloading a method, the signature of child method should be compatible with that of parent method, or the interface method.

In OOP, SOLID stands for Single responsibility, Open-closed, Liskov substitution, Interface segregation and Dependency inversion. [The Liskov substitution principe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) is applied to the arguments of the method.

The [PHPDoc](https://www.phpdoc.org/) is easier when arguments are in method signature, and your Best PHP IDEs (like PhpStorm for example) can help you when you write a call of the method.

With the second situation, you have to check the type of each variable and define each default value if null. The Liskov substitution principe is not obvious in this situation. You lose the signature of method.

I prefer the first situation.

Answer (score 1):

As usual - no single cure for all diseases. For homogeneous data - array fits well, otherwise - use different parameters for name hinting, like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With the second choice

```
$args = [x1 => x1,x2 => x2,x3 => x3,x4 => x4...]
public function xyz($args){
     x1=$args[x1];
     x2=$args[x2];
     x3=$args[x3];
     x4=$args[x4];
}
```

You have done the same job than the "[extract](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.extract.php)" and "[compact](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.compact.php)" functions

So you can rewrite your 2nd choice like this :

```
$args = compact('x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4');
public function xyz($args){
     extract($args);
}
```

I prefer the first choice.